# Uber API to detect rides

Tags: uber-api

Is it possible to use the Uber API to detect rides that originated from the Uber app?

I'm trying to get a machine learning system to learn when you are using uber.

Answer (score 0):

No, whether a ride originated from the Uber app or from a separate integration is not a field/endpoint in the current Uber API.

Not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for but something that might be helpful is the /history endpoint. "The User Activity endpoint returns a limited amount of data about a user’s lifetime activity with Uber. The response will include pickup and dropoff times, the city the trips took place in, the distance of past requests, and information about which products were requested."

Documentation: https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/history-get

Comment: I'm looking to understand/learn when a person takes Uber, to where (work, movies, etc) and how often so that an ml system can predict next rides. But sounds like that's not possible.